# Is there a way to create a pull request that creates new branch in RepoA from RepoB from CD pipeline in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task, azure-task-groups

I have a scenarios when i need to create a new branch pull request in Repo A from the chnages done in Repo B using the CD pipeline

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure there is no set way how to do it from a CI/CD pipeline (please correct me if I'm wrong), but it's definitely doable if you are ready to put together a custom solution.

In this case, I would suggest something similar to this workflow:

- First of all, set up a pipeline that is triggered when changes are committed to `Repository B`.
- After the pipeline checkout is done, create a script that removes remote URLs for `Repository B` and adds URLs for `Repository A`. That would look something like this:

  ```
   - script: |
       git remote rm origin
       git remote add origin $(your_repo_url)
  ```
- Then install the ssh key that allows you to access `Repository A`. You can use the `Install SSH key` task YAML template.
- Create a script that commits and pushes the branch you previously checked out on `Repository B` to `Repository A` (in a similar way as the previous script).
- Finally, use your git repository hosting service API to create a pull request.

Comment: Instead of using API you can use this task [CreatePullRequest](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk.CreatePullRequest)

Comment: Yes, that would work as well, thanks! Didn't know about this task.

Comment: All credits goes to @shayki-abramczyk [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7409220/shayki-abramczyk)

Comment: @Krzysztof Madej Thanks for the response.

I did check on the [CreatePullRequest](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShaykiAbramczyk)   task, but it doesn't not create a pull request from one repo to another repo and at the same time create a new branch.

What it does is, it creates a pull request from one existing branch to another existing branch and within the same repo.

plz correct me if I am wrong, really appreciate you response guys.

Comment: @LJ, thanks for the response, will try to implement the same and see how it works out.

Comment: I think he meant to use `CreatePullRequest` task as an alternative to the 5th bullet point in the workflow I offered as a solution. Instead of using your git repository hosting service API to create pull request, use `CreatePullRequest` task.

Comment: @LJ okay got it, thanks for the clarification :)